# How to pass value from my android java class to php using JSON?

Tags: java, android, json

i need help.

just want to know how to pass value to my php using JSON?

in my CategoryFragment code i set value to my cid

```
cid = catid;
```

now i want to pass this value to my php using JSON in this code

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/products.php");
```

this is my **CategoryFragment.java**

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/18/2015.
 */
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(String id,String name) {
        CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", id);
        bundle.putString("name", name);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public CategoryFragment () {
    }

    EditText tpid, tpname;
    String cid;
    String cname;

    String myJSON;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    GridView productgridview;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    public static String products_id = "products_id";
    public static String products_name = "products_name";
    public static String products_price = "products_price";
    public static String products_image = "products_image";

    Boolean InternetAvailable = false;
    Seocnd detectconnection;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorylayout, container, false);

        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        tpid = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpid);
        tpname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpname);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            String catid = getArguments().getString("id");
            String catname = getArguments().getString("name");

            tpid.setText(catid);
            tpname.setText(catname);
            cid = catid;
            cname = catname;
        }

        productgridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.productgridview);

        //new DownloadJSON().execute();

        detectconnection = new Seocnd(getActivity());
        InternetAvailable = detectconnection.InternetConnecting();
        if (InternetAvailable) {
            getProduct();
        } else {
            NointernetFragment fragment = new NointernetFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public void getProduct(){
        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle(cname);
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/products.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                    jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");

                    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject p = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("products_id", p.getString("products_id"));
                        map.put("products_name", p.getString("products_name"));
                        map.put("products_price", p.getString("products_price"));
                        map.put("products_image", p.getString("products_image"));
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the GridView
                productgridview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        DownloadJSON g = new DownloadJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(2);
    }
}
```

after i pass the value i want to use it in this part of my php code

```
$cid = "CID value here from java";
```

here is the complete php code..

**products.php**

```
<?php
    include('dbconnection.php');

    $cid = "CID value here from java";

    $statement = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_price, p.products_image FROM products p INNER JOIN products_description pd ON p.products_id=pd.products_id WHERE p.products_status='1' ORDER BY p.products_sort_order ASC");

    $products = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement)){
      array_push($products,
        array(
        'products_id'=>$row[0],
        'products_name'=>$row[1],
        'products_price'=>$row[2],
        'products_image'=>"http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/images/".$row[3]
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("products"=>$products));
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

help me to construct my code.. thanks..

Comment: Please only post relevant code. We don't need your entire codebase ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code for add parameters into http post request.I hope it will help you..!

```
    //Post Data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", "testid"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "testvalue"));

    //Encoding POST data
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // finally make POST request.
```